# General Ruby conversions

Tags: ruby

1. How does `Integer(543543534)` work given that `Integer` is a
   class? It doesn't seem to work with every class:

   ```
    Numeric '4532432'
    #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `Numeric' for main:Object
   ```
2. Is there a general way to construct an instance of a class `SomeClass` from `SomeClass` and a string `'somestring'` besides trying `SomeClass.new('somestring')` or defining `#to_X`?

Comment: `Integer` must be a method, so let's see where it comes from:  `method(:Integer).owner #=> Kernel`. Ah, [Kernel#Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer).

Comment: Yup, the Q#1 was a stupid question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Your assumption does not hold. `Integer` is not a class there.
2. You have to define that as a method (in `Kernel`).

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Integer(543543534)`, you invoke [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method, which converts argument to `Fixnum` or `Bignum`. And `Kernel` module is being included by `Object`, so this is just a method call on `Object`, it isn't related to `Integer` class.